# Server to Firebase HTTP POST results in response message 200

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using Java code (scroll down to view) I am sending a notification message to my Android using FCM, when providing the correct server key token I receive the response message seen below.

The following response message is received from FCM after

```
Response: 200
 Success Message: '{"multicast_id":-1,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}'
Error Message: ''

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This means the server key token is correct and there's some sort of authorization established with FCM. When I use incorrect server key token(s) I get a different error message. However, the message above although labeled "Success Message*" still states that the success value =0 and the failure value =1, error:InvalidRegistration. **If this is indeed an error, does the error imply the notification was not received by FCM, or not by the endpoint Android application?**

**Android App**

The Android application is able to receive notifications from FCM using the console. **Does this mean the Android app is set to receive the same notifications from the Java server I wrote or does the app need additional code to process these notifications that are not sent from the console?**

(Just for information purspose, code is clean and runs without errors, not all files of the project are shown below, just the relevant main function and HTTP POST file).

**Java server**

```
public class Sample {

    private static String SERVER_KEY = "AAAA-NCJais:APA91b----CENSORED-------";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        com.pushraven.Pushraven.setKey(SERVER_KEY);


        // create Notification object 
        Notification raven = new Notification();

        HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("Hello", "World!");
        data.put("Rami", "Imar");
        data.put("Test1", "Test2");

        // build raven message using the builder pattern
    raven.to("/topics/ALL")
        .collapse_key("a_collapse_key")
        .priority(1)
        .delay_while_idle(true)
        .time_to_live(100)
        .restricted_package_name("com.example.******")
        .dry_run(true)
        .data(data)
        .title("Testing")
        .body("Hello World!");

        // push the raven message
        FcmResponse response = Pushraven.push(raven);

        // alternatively set static notification first.
        Pushraven.setNotification(raven);
        response = Pushraven.push();

        // prints response code and message
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

--------------------------------- other file ------------------------------

```
public static FcmResponse push(Notification n) {    
    if(FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY == null){
        System.err.println("No Server-Key has been defined.");
        return null;
    }

    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    try{
        String url = API_URL;

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Set POST headers
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");


        // Send POST body
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(n.toJSON());
        writer.close();
        wr.close();

        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        con.getResponseCode();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new FcmResponse(con);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`InvalidRegistration`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) error means that the token you're sending the message to is invalid:

> Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

Double check the value you're passing in your `to` parameter. In your code, I see that you're using `news`. If you were intending to send to a *topic*, you'll have to add the prefix `/topics/`. So it should be something like `/topics/news/`. See the [Topic Messaging docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) for more details.

Comment: Any other token will result in the response code:  **Response: 401
 Success Message: ''
Error Message: '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>The request&#39;s Authentification (Server-) Key contained an invalid or malformed FCM-Token.**  I checked many times, due to this as well it seems that I am using the correct token. Perhaps the error message is indicating that the Android app is failing to receive the notification? Or is the error message only pointing out that the transmission to Firebase is failing?

Comment: 401 is received when you're using the wrong Server Key. Are you absolutely positive that you're using the Server Key found in the ***Cloud Messaging*** tab in your Firebase Console and **not** the *Web API Key*?

Comment: If you are using the correct Server Key and still receiving 401, I suggest contacting [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to have a deeper look into the issue. The 401 error is between the communication of your App server and FCM server, where the FCM server is rejecting the message due to an unauthorized request.

Comment: Also, can you try out if the same message occurs if you send the message using a cURL request or using Postman? See here -- http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=201704100308348000543

Comment: Yes I am using the key from the cloud messaging tab, it's longer than the API key. I am positive that I use the correct key, I also generated a new key to try it, same result, once I deleted the key from the console it gave a 404 message instead of 200. I will create a new FCM project to test this throughly and follow up on its status. **As for the 200 return code, does this mean there is an error between the communication of my App server and FCM server or does this error checking also extend to the Android app ?**

Comment: It's just between your Server and FCM. The 200 OK response just means that they were able to communicate, the error message just says the reason why FCM is rejecting the message. Do try to send the message using Postman/cURL as well. See if the error is the same.

Comment: Using Postman with the following body results in a positive 200 message with return of a valid message ID.** {
 "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
 "data": {
  "message": "This is an FCM Topic Message!",
  "restricted_package_name":"com.example.*****",
  "title":"Testing",
  "body":"Hello World!"
 }
}** The issue seems to be in the "// build raven message using the builder pattern" part of my Java code, I receive the following return message from FCM when using (edited Java code see above): **Response: 200
 Success Message: '{"message_id":-1}'**