# I get InvalidRegistration while sending notification to Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notification using php curl to android but I get this:

```
{"multicast_id":6460600019383907027,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Im getting token in android with the below code:

```
public String getToken() throws IOException {
    return FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43314282/4625829) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41279022/4625829). Make sure that you're not changing the format of the token in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I had minimum field length in database for storing instance id so full id would not be saved when I increased field length to 300 it worked

Answer (score 0):

your  device id was wrong or you r not using device id as string you have not mentioned which language you r using .i got same issue in php  .i got device id using select query  and directly asighn to fields .i got same error .but then i converter value as string in php i got successfull result i got notification
so check your device id

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid Registration Token    200 + error:InvalidRegistration Check the
>   format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it
>   matches the registration token the client app receives from
>   registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add
>   additional characters.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Saving reg id to shared preferences
        storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

        // sending reg id to your server
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }
```